# Why Is My Swift Combine Publisher Not Publishing?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I am working with Swift Combine in a SwiftUI App. I've had success using it until recently. I am attempting to use a ViewModel to set value when using combine but it does not appear to be getting updated. What's odd is I have another ViewModel that is working. I am using Firebase as a database.

#### ListingRepository

This file starts a listener from Firestore and sets an `@Published` property with a array of listings.

```
class ListingRepository: ObservableObject {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    @Published var listings = [Listing]()
    
    init() {
        startSnapshotListener()
    }
    
    func startSnapshotListener() {
        db.collection(FirestoreCollection.listings).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
            } else {
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("No Listings.")
                    return
                }
                
                self.listings = documents.compactMap { listing in
                    do {
                        return try listing.data(as: Listing.self)
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Working ViewModel

This is the ViewModel that is working. I am using Combine here to map over the listings and create `ListRowViewModel`s. The code works and I can populate the rows successfully.

```
class MarketplaceViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var listingRepository = ListingRepository()
    @Published var listingRowViewModels = [ListingRowViewModel]()
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        listingRepository
            .$listings
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .map { listings in
                listings.map { listing in
                    ListingRowViewModel(listing: listing)
                }
            }
            .assign(to: \.listingRowViewModels, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

#### ViewModel Not Working

This ViewModel is for an account view. I started simply by using the count() operator to try and capture the number of listings and then display this on the `AccountView`. When I build and run the view is not updated.

```
class AccountViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var listingRepository = ListingRepository()
    
    @Published var numberOfListings: Int = 0
    @
        
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        listingRepository
            .$listings
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .count()
            .assign(to: \.numberOfListings, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

Upon further inspection it appears the publisher is not being called. I used a sink to try and print the result of the count and nothing gets printed.

```
class AccountViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var listingRepository = ListingRepository()
    
    @Published var numberOfListings: Int = 0
    @
        
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        listingRepository
            .$listings
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .count()
            .sink {
                print("Number Of Listings: \($0)")
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

`MarketplaceViewModel` and `AccountViewModel` are used in `MarketplaceView` and AccountView`.

#### MarketplaceView

```
struct MarketplaceView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var marketplaceViewModel = MarketplaceViewModel()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(marketPlaceViewModel.listingRowViewModels[1].listing.name)
    }
}
```

#### AccountView

```
struct AccountView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var accountViewModel = AccountViewModel()
        
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(accountViewModel.numberOfListings)                     }
    }
}
```

These two views are presented in `ContentView`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Group{
           
                TabView {
                    MarketplaceView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "shippingbox")
                            Text("Marketplace")
                        }.tag(0) // MarketplaceView
                    AccountView(user: testUser1)
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "person")
                            Text("Account")
                        }.tag(1) // AccountView
                } // TabView
                .accentColor(.white)
        }// Group
    }
}
```

I'm very puzzled why this is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is `MarketplaceViewModel` and `AccountViewModel` used?

Comment: They are used in MarketplaceView and AccountView which is on ContentView.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention `ContentView`.

Comment: @Alexander You are correct I edited the post.

Comment: This is a lot of code, which is usually a good thing (better to have too much rather than too little), but could you narrow it down to take out the things that aren't relevant to your issue?

Comment: It seems to me that when you say `@Published var listingRepository = ListingRepository()` you are making a totally new ListingRepository, so that when your ObservableObject ListingRepository changes, it isn't this one.

Comment: @matt how would you only make one?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955859/341994. What you are doing seems to me to be exactly what that answer says not to do.

Comment: @Alexander I've simplified the text.

Comment: @matt I tested this by commenting out the ListingRepository in MarketplaceViewModel so there was only one. This did not work.

Comment: It looks to me like you're creating a new `AccountViewModel` in every `AccountView`. This doesn't make sense. SwiftUI View structs are ephemeral. You would benefit from watching https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/ and https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/

Comment: Try replacing every use of `@ObservedObject` with `@StateObject`.

Comment: @PeterSchorn I tried this but it did not work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `addSnapshotListener` is being called and `ListingRepository.listings` is in fact being changed in this closure (as opposed to an error being thrown)?

Comment: @PeterSchorn I have. It’s loading the data for MarketplaceView

Comment: The `count` operator in your problem. I should've noticed it earlier. It only emits after the upstream publisher finishes, and a `Published.Publisher` never finishes. Read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/count()).

Comment: What you probably meant is to retrieve the count of the `listings` array. For that, use `.map { $0.count }`.

Comment: @PeterSchorn. Brilliant! Thank you very much! This solved the problem. I will be sure to read the docs more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's ObservedObject instead of of a StateObject

Comment: Kindly provide example code with screenshot of output to support your answer.