How to initialize a property so that the onChange does not track its change of value until properly initialized
I have a configuration view, with several toggle buttons that need to save its state to disk whenever the user clicks any of them. To simplify the problem, I've just created an example project with a single Toggle:
struct MyApp: App {
    
    @State var session = AppSession()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
            .environment(session)
        }
    }
}

@Observable public class AppSession {
    public var value: Bool = true
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(AppSession.self) private var session: AppSession
    @State private var enableToggle: Bool = false //this value is set here to avoid having to make the property optional, but its initial value is set on the onAppear.
    
    var body: some View {
    
            VStack {
                Toggle("Test Toggle", isOn: $enableToggle)
                
            }
            .onAppear {
                print("onAppear")
                self.enableToggle = session.value
            }
            .onChange(of: enableToggle) { oldValue, newValue in
                print("Changed oldValue: \(oldValue) newValue: \(newValue)")
                //saveConfigurationToDisk()
            }
    }
}

The problem I'm facing is that the onChange event is triggered the moment the view is rendered and before the user taps on the toggle, causing an unnecessary save of the state to disk, and this happens because on the onAppear we are setting the initial value for the property (which cannot be set on a custom init because it comes from an environment object).
I can start adding variables to track the first execution of the onChange to be able to ignore it, but I have the feeling that there has to be a better way, a more swiftui one.
Is there any other way to initialize properties whose value comes from the environment so that the onChange is not trigered until they have been initialized?

did you try to use initial parameter of onChange https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:initial:_:)-8wgw9

I think any solution here would boil down to "adding variables to track the first execution of the onChange to be able to ignore it". It's just a matter of how much boilerplate you want to avoid. You can for example create your own DynamicProperty that wraps two @States.

@timbretimbre OP is trying to do kind of the opposite of initial - to not fire onChange initially, and also not fire onChange on the first time the value changes.

Change class to struct, pass binding to value to child View. Only ever pass Views the exact data they need not whole objects.

@timbretimbre I've tried the initial parameter but as Sweeper says, I was trying to achieve the opposite, which is to skip the  execution of onChange that triggers when setting the initial value on the onChange.  After posting the comment I found a post with a solution that will add to this one for others to see. However, I'm going to try some of the suggestions reported below, and see if they fit better. Will report back.

Try this different approach using the data model directly with @Bindable, such as:
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(AppSession.self) private var session: AppSession
    
    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var session = session // <--- here
        VStack {
            Toggle("Test Toggle", isOn: $session.value) // <--- here
        }
        .onChange(of: session.value) { oldValue, newValue in
            print("----> onChange oldValue: \(oldValue) newValue: \(newValue)")
            //saveConfigurationToDisk()
        }
    }
}

This approach IMHO answers, How to initialize a property ..., it is initialised in the data model,
and ... so that the onChange does not track its change of value until properly initialized, only the changes are tracked and actioned in onChange
but not the initial value setting.
It is another way of achieving what you want without the intermediate enableToggle.

I liked this approach. I did not know i could declare Bindable vars in the middle of the code. I've tried to implement this solution, however, the example provided was an oversimplification of the real problem, and did not work in my case. But as it reallly solves the problem exposed in the code exampe provided I've maked it as the accepted answer. Thanks @workingdog_support_Ukraine

The code below shows basically what @workingdog said, with some additional examples, including an observable singleton and various ways to use it.
A singleton can make working with Previews more flexible, among other things.
import SwiftUI
import Observation

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    //Binding to observable singleton
    @Bindable var session = AppSession.session
    
    //Initializer
    init() {
        //configure your session here as needed
        session.enableToggle = false
    }
    
    //Body
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

//Observable singleton
@Observable class AppSession {
    var enableToggle: Bool = true
    var showWelcome: Bool = false
    static let session = AppSession()
    private init() {}
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    //Binding to observable singleton
    @Bindable var session = AppSession.session

    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Toggle("Test Toggle", isOn: $session.enableToggle)
            Toggle("Show Welcome", isOn: $session.showWelcome)
            ToggleInfo()
            ToggleButton()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ToggleInfo: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Toggle is \(AppSession.session.enableToggle ? "enabled" : "disabled")")
            .foregroundStyle(AppSession.session.enableToggle ? .green : .red)
    }
}

struct ToggleButton: View {
    
    //State values
    @State private var showButton: Bool = false
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        let showWelcome = AppSession.session.showWelcome
        
        HStack {
            if showButton {
                Button("Toggle Test Toggle"){
                    AppSession.session.enableToggle.toggle()
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: showWelcome) {
            withAnimation {
                showButton = showWelcome
            }
        }
        
    }
}
//Preview
#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


this SO post's answers indicate that using a singleton with ObservableObject/Observable is a bad idea  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63955662/swiftui-classes-that-conforms-observableobject-should-be-singleton

@workingdogsupportUkraine Thanks for the link. What the answer says is not at all that using a singleton is a bad idea generally, but that it should not be assumed, in that particular use case, that a singleton is needed. A singleton has its use if you need a shared state (like a session or app settings maybe), but it can also be a poor choice based on other considerations. I will bookmark that answer as it may be pertinent to another question I answered, so thanks again for sharing and bringing it up.

As explained in some of the comments, I've ended up implementing a different solution to those provided, so I'm shaing it here, which consists in creating a subview of ContentView with an initializer that accepts an AppSession object, and having the ContentView just call that suvbiew on the body passing AppSession as parameter. That way I can move all the intialization that was happening on the onApper to the init method of the subview, that no longer has an environment variable. I was hoping for a more "swiftui native" solutions, but works well and is very very simple to implement.

If you found an answer different than the ones already provided, you should add it as answer here yourself and provide the code. The explanation in the above comment is not sufficient and definitely not testable by anyone.

Assuming that you actually need the environment variable for other child views:
The easiest way would be to create the state property with the correct desired initial value.
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @State private var session = AppSession()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(initialValue: session.value)
                .environment(session)
        }
    }
}

@Observable final class AppSession {
    public var value = true
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(AppSession.self) private var session
    @State private var enableToggle: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Test Toggle", isOn: $enableToggle)
        }
        .onChange(of: enableToggle) { oldValue, newValue in
            print("Changed oldValue: \(oldValue) newValue: \(newValue)")
        }
    }

    init(initialValue: Bool) {
        _enableToggle = State(initialValue: initialValue)
    }
}

In your demo code, ContentView does not use the AppSession instance at all, which is why the code could easily be shortened by simply omitting the environment variable:
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @State private var session = AppSession()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(initialValue: session.value)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var enableToggle: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Test Toggle", isOn: $enableToggle)
        }
        .onChange(of: enableToggle) { oldValue, newValue in
            print("Changed oldValue: \(oldValue) newValue: \(newValue)")
        }
    }

    init(initialValue: Bool) {
        _enableToggle = State(initialValue: initialValue)
    }
}

For the sake of completeness, here is an example in which the AppSession instance is used directly in ContentView and is made available to child views as an environment object:
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @State private var session = AppSession()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(session: session)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Bindable var session: AppSession

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Test Toggle", isOn: $session.value)
        }
        .onChange(of: session.value) { oldValue, newValue in
            print("Changed oldValue: \(oldValue) newValue: \(newValue)")
        }
        .environment(session)
    }
}

